# What are all these "ad.doubleclick.net" pages I'm secretly visiting?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I'm using IE 10 and a few pages that I visit appear to be constantly visiting ad sites behind the scenes.  For example after going to a pastebin post I went to select "Back" to only find I was returning to the same site.  After right clicking on the back button I get the following trail of sites I've "visited":

[image]

[DoubleClick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoubleClick) appears to be a service from Google, however I don't understand why there are so many supposed navigations to the URL, when I haven't click on any links.

Is this a sign of ad/malware?  Why are there so many supposed navigations to the site, when I haven't interacted with the site at all?

---

This is what the browser history looks like:

[image]

So it appears that the history isn't capturing these, but the "Back" button history is.

Comment: Not sure this is a viable question.  [DoubleClick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoubleClick) is part of Google (easily found out by googling it :) ) Did you do a malware scan?  What'd it say? Perhaps instead of asking What it is (which you can easily find out), you may want to rephrase your question to ask Why they're showing up in your browsing history in IE.  To that end, does this happen all the time? Or only when you visit a specific site?  Have you cleared your history to see if they return?

Comment: @techie007 You've pointed to what it is, but why does my browser (or the site) cause this to be visited hundreds of time if left alone for a few minutes?  Also I do ask what's going on here after the picture.

Comment: @techie007 I've updated my question re: browser history.

Comment: "Is this a sign of ad/malware?" Did you check for yourself? It's not (in the traditional sense anyway, since you now know it belongs to Google).  "Or is this a scheme for the sites to generate more revenue from silent navigations to the ad sites?": How are we to know this?  It could be, it could be an accidental loop, etc.  Can you provide an example URL we can check out?

Comment: @techie007 visit any [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/GXfxjy4Z).  But it's not limited to just pastebin.  I've noticed this behavior on other sites as well.  I've also updated the question removing the "scheme" question.  You're right that it didn't belong.

Comment: Your PasteBin isn't doing it to me (IE10 Windows 8). Can you reproduce this on a another computer?  You still haven't told us if you've scanned for malware yet.  If you suspect it's malware, what steps have to taken to test that theory?  Back to IE: Do you have IE's tracking protection turned on (Hmm, I wonder why they made tracking protection. ;) )?  I usually keep it on, but ensuring it was off for PasteBin still isn't causing anything like that to show up in the back button history (even though the ads show up now), even if I navigate around.

Comment: Is IE in a default state when this happens? Do you have any 3rd party add-ons turned on (Google toolbar?) Do you have Flash installed/enabled?

Comment: What does you host file look like? Is it stock or have you modified it in anyway?

Comment: From my research on the issue this seems to be an issue isolated to IE involving the way the browser chooses to render iframes (which contain ads), it has been around for a longtime since IE8.  Honestly it is probably not spyware/malware; just an incompatibly between current ad implementations and IE.

Comment: @techie007 lot's of comments, but no answers.  Instead of commenting, why not collect your research together and answer the question at hand?

Comment: cc @hwshadow ^^

Comment: @Kronos, the point is, you're not doing any research, nor are you answering questions that make it possible for us to actually give you an answer that solves your problem.  Anyhow, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a sign of ad/malware

Technically speaking this isn't ad- or mal-ware however it is a common problem found with the way that Internet Explorer (8, 9, and 10) handles DoubleClick ads from Google.

> Why are there so many supposed navigations to the site, when I haven't interacted with the site at all?

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening.  I'll continue to do more research and see what I can find.

---

The question that you didn't ask and should've is this:

> How do I stop this from happening?

This can be easily stopped by simply adding `http://ad.doubleclick.net` to the list of "untrusted site".  Navigate to "Internet Options" and select the security tab.  Select the "Restricted Sites" zone and then "Sites" **(1)**.  Type in the address `http://ad.doubleclick.net` into the text box **(2)** and then select "Add" **(3)**.

[image]

This should stop the behavior you're talking about here.  Another site I found that may be helpful to add would be `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net`.

Comment: on other browsers, I do believe this is a staple of most adblock filters.